# Integral of Gaussian Density with Log

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $f_{0}(x) = Ce^{-(x+\alpha)^2/2}$ and $f_1(x) = Ce^{-(x-\alpha)^2/2}$ where $C$ is a normalizing constant such that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_1(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_0(x)dx = 1, \text{and} \ \alpha > 0 $$

Prove that

$$\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_0(x)\ln(f_0(x)+f_1(x))dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_0(x)\ln(f_0(x))dx$$

My approach: To show, 
$$\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_0(x)\ln(f_0(x)+f_1(x))dx - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_0(x)\ln(f_0(x))dx = 0$$

that is,
$$\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_0(x)\ln(1+\frac{f_1(x)}{f_0(x)})dx = 0$$

that is, 
$$\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x+\alpha)^2/2)}\ln(1+e^{2x\alpha})dx = 0$$

Substituting, $x+\alpha = t$,
$$\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2/2}\ln(1+e^{2(t\alpha-\alpha^2)})dt = 0$$

Thus if we can prove that 
$$\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2/2}\ln(1+e^{2(t\alpha-\alpha^2)})dt = 0$$

then the proof is done.

$$ \begin{align} 
&~ \lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2/2}\ln(1+e^{2(t\alpha-\alpha^2)})dt \\
= &~ \lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty} \Bigg[\int_{-\infty}^{-\alpha}e^{-t^2/2}\ln(1+e^{2(t\alpha-\alpha^2)})dt
+ \int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha}e^{-t^2/2}\ln(1+e^{2(t\alpha-\alpha^2)})dt \\
+ &~ \int_{\alpha}^{\infty}e^{-t^2/2}\ln(1+e^{2(t\alpha-\alpha^2)})dt\Bigg]
\end{align}$$

Any directions on how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\alpha>0$. Applying 
$$ \ln(1+x)<x, \forall x>0. $$
you have
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_{-\infty}^{\alpha}e^{-t^2/2}\ln(1+e^{2(t\alpha-\alpha^2)})dt \\
&\le&\int_{-\infty}^{\alpha}e^{-t^2/2}e^{2(t\alpha-\alpha^2)}dt\\
&=&\int_{-\infty}^{\alpha}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(t-2\alpha)^2}dt\\
&=&\int_{-\infty}^{-\alpha}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}dt\to0\text{ as }\alpha\to\infty.
\end{eqnarray}
Repeating this for other integrals, you will get the answer.

Comment: Where did $\alpha$ go in the last equality.

Comment: @minion, in the last line.

Comment: How is $\int_{-\infty}^{-\alpha}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(t-2\alpha)^2}dt = \int_{-\infty}^{-\alpha}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}dt$. My point of confusion is due to limit of $\alpha$ on both the integrand as well upper limit of integration.

Comment: Are you using the decomposition of the integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ as $-\infty$ to $-\alpha$, $-\alpha$ to $\alpha$ and $\alpha$ to $\infty$?

Comment: Using the substitute $u=t-2\alpha $.